# Prefilling subsequent Docusign tabs

Tags: curl, docusignapi

We have templates that contain multiple tabs for a UBI Number. I got our REST request to get the first template occurrence per page of this field to prefill, but not the others that follow. I was wondering if it would fill in all fields with the same tabLabel or if it just finds the first occurrence, fills it in and then exits? We're using cURL and PHP along with REST. Code example:

```
"templateRoles" => array(
    array(
        "tabs" => array(
            "textTabs" => array (
                array ("tabLabel" => "license_number", "value" => $license_number),
                array ("tabLabel" => "ubi_number", "value" => "$ubi_number"),
                array ("tabLabel" => "trade_name", "value" => $trade_name)
            )
        ),
        "email" => "$applicant_email",
        "name" => $applicant_name,
        "roleName" => "Applicant"
    )   
),
"status" => "sent");
```

This is only a bit of the cURL request and like I said, it fills in the first occurrence of the UBI Number field on each page but none of the ones that follow in the same template page. Any idea to why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your envelope contains multiple like-named fields (in your example, **ubi_number**), then in your REST API request where you're attempting to populate those fields (i.e., put the same value in all fields that have the tab label **ubi_number**), prepend the characters **\\*** to the tab label.  That is, your tab label specified in the request would be:  **\\*ubi_number**

Doing this should make all fields that have the tab label **ubi_number** populate with the value you specify in the request.  For more details about this, see page 297 of the DocuSign REST API guide, under the heading "Automatically Populating Tabs":  http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf

Comment: So I'm using variables in my cURL call. Would I just do this = `\\*$ubi_number`?

Comment: Never mind. I reread your amazing answer that works! Thank you Kim.

Comment: FYI This was previously addressed through this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181359/docusign-how-to-prefill-multiple-text-tabs-with-the-same-label/18197288#18197288