# Incorrect population of text fields with identical data labels

Tags: docusignapi

I'm creating an envelope with several documents.
The first document contains 2 text fields that share the same data label.
According to the documentation found here,
https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-field-properties

> Note: If you set the data labels to be exactly the same for fields of the same type, the field data becomes linked. When the sender prepares the document or template, or when the signer signs the document, an entry in any one of the linked fields is automatically populated into all fields with the same data label. This behavior is constrained by the Data Population Scope setting for the account. This setting can restrict the entry replication to just within the same uploaded file, or extend it to all files in the document. Currently, the Data Population Scope setting is only available through the classic experience

Regardless of the value of **Data Population Scope** (found in the classic admin UI), only one field gets populated.

Does anyone know why both fields do not get populated correctly?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocuSign: How to prefill multiple text tabs with the same label?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181359/docusign-how-to-prefill-multiple-text-tabs-with-the-same-label)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When populating the values through the API there's a trick you need to do.  You need to append the string literal `\\*` before the tabLabel you are trying to match for all your tabs.  For example:

```
"tabLabel": "\\*SocialSecurityTab",
```

Will match all tabs that have tabLabel "SocialSecurityTab".

For a more detailed answer see:
[DocuSign: How to prefill multiple text tabs with the same label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181359/docusign-how-to-prefill-multiple-text-tabs-with-the-same-label/18197288#18197288)