# Docusign DateSigned tabs not being created

Tags: elixir, docusignapi

Using the docusign API to create an envelope which has signature fields and initial fields which are converted into tabs.

I want to add "date signed" tabs for each signature, but the dateSignedTab isn't having any effect. The form we are using has multiple datesigned fields with name: `date_signed_1DocuSignDateSigned`

I have found no useful documentation or examples of dateSigned tabs. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
%{compositeTemplates: [%{document: %{documentBase64: "Base.encode64(file)",
       documentId: 75,
       name: "SADF SDF, Accounts Assistant (Accounts) - DAILY, PAYE.pdf",
       transformPdfFields: "true"},
     inlineTemplates: [%{recipients: %{carbonCopies: [],
          signers: [%{email: "jmurph@gmail.com", name: "sadf sdf",
             recipientId: 2, routingOrder: 2,


             tabs: 
               %{dateSignedTabs: [%{documentId: 75, tabLabel: "date_signed_1\\*"}],
               signHereTabs: [%{documentId: 75, tabLabel: "signature_1\\*"}]}}]}, 


             sequence: "1"}]},
   %{document: %{documentBase64: "Base.encode64(file)", documentId: 76,
       name: "SADF SDF, Accounts Assistant (Accounts) - DAILY, FORM.pdf",
       transformPdfFields: "true"},
     inlineTemplates: [%{recipients: %{carbonCopies: [%{email: "murph@hotmail.com",
             name: "Jack Murphy", recipientId: 23, routingOrder: 3}],
          signers: [%{email: "jmurph@gmail.com", name: "sadf sdf",
             recipientId: 2, routingOrder: 2,
             tabs: %{dateSignedTabs: [%{documentId: 76,
                  tabLabel: "date_signed_1\\*"}],
               signHereTabs: [%{documentId: 76,
                  tabLabel: "signature_1\\*"}]}}]}, sequence: "2"}]}],
  emailBlurb: "\n\nddd - agreement: sadf sdf, Accounts Assistant (Accounts)",
  emailSubject: "ddd - agreement: sadf sdf, Accounts Assistant (Accounts)",
  status: "sent"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the complete tabLabel so that it matches your form field name.

```
tabLabel: "date_signed_1DocuSignDateSigned\\*"
```

You are confusing `\\*` operator with a wild card search.  The operator is used when you have several tabs with the same tabLabel and you'd like all of them to start out with the same initial value. The tabLabel will still have to match completely with your form field name.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197288/1219543) for more context and additional documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/#automatically-populating-tabs)

Comment: do you work for docusign or something?

I changed it to this: ------------------------------

    tabs: %{dateSignedTabs: [%{documentId: 89,
                  tabLabel: "date_signed_1DocuSignDateSigned\\*"}] -------------------------- But no luck

Comment: Yes I work for DocuSign. I think it should be `\\*`  instead of `\*` .. If that does not work can you please share your Pdf Document.