# Filling multiple Text Tabs with the same label

Tags: docusignapi

According to [DocuSign: How to prefill multiple text tabs with the same label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181359/docusign-how-to-prefill-multiple-text-tabs-with-the-same-label), by appending `\\*` to my Text Tab label will make it work and it does.

However, when I have Text Tab labels that end with the same character sequence, the incorrect value will be set: `ServiceName` and `Name` Text Tabs will both get populated with the value I set for `Name`.

Is there a way for this not to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\\*` syntax is a wildcard, so if you want your API request to populate the **Name** field but *not* the **ServiceName** field, then you can do so by having your API request specify `tabLabel` = `Name\\*` (this will populate any field that has a label starting with the value "Name").

For example, this JSON within my **Create Envelope** API request...

```
"tabs": {
  "textTabs": [
      {
          "tabLabel": "Name\\*",
          "value": "value_inserted_via_API"
      }
  ]
}
```

...populates the `Name` field in the Envelope, but not the `ServiceName` field:

[image: DS Envelope Fields]